# Data Frame to CSV no longer working as it did in previous days

Tags: python

I was able to create a code that would take a list of tickers and find options contracts for them using yahoo-fin. The code was working fine for a couple days, however, now, the code does not append options data from the list of tickers, but instead; it only prints the options contracts for the last ticker in the list.

mode='a' is what was used to continually append the data retrieved for each option contract to the end of the csv without overwriting the previous data.
Any help is appreciated!

Here is the code:

````
stocks = ['AAPL','AMZN']
for stock in stocks:
    try:
        pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
        chain = options.get_options_chain(stock, 'October 15, 2021')
        print(chain)
    except:
        ValueError

df = pd.DataFrame(chain, columns=['Contract Name', 'Last Trade Date', 'Strike', 'Last Price', 'Bid', 'Ask', 'Change', 'Volume', 'Implied Volatility'])
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\etcetc', index=False, header=True, mode='a')```
````

Comment: Remove the bare `except:` to see what's going wrong.

Comment: I originally had to have the ``` except: value error ``` in order to have the code continue through tickers in the list that did not have options data. I removed the except, and I get an indentation error: unexpected unindent.

Comment: Okay, then you need to fix the indentation now.